# MSSQL - Invalid column name with Java/JTDS

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I have read all the threads about my problem and all of them finish without solution... 
Anyway I hope to be luckier...

I'm trying to use JDBC to connect to the MSSQL db.
I used the driver from Microsoft sqljdbc4.jar and I had no problem.
Since I have to switch to JTDS (I'm using 1.2.8) I got this exception when I try to run the same SQL string:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'id'.    at
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2894)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2334)   at
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:643)  at
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:506)
    at
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeQuery(JtdsStatement.java:1433)
```

The string is

```
SELECT tabledatastoreitem.name, tabledatastoreitem.path
FROM tabledatastoreitem, store, service, serviceprovider
WHERE tabledatastoreitem.store_id = store.id
    AND store.service_store_id = service.id
    AND service.serviceprovider_id = serviceprovider.id
    AND serviceprovider.name = 'SystemIService'
    AND store.createdttm < CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(MI, -7, GETDATE()));
```

Any idea?

Comment: Any references to any earlier threads that you read?

Comment: Can you add the related create Statements from your tables?

Comment: so do your store/service/serviceprovider tables have an `id` field?

Comment: You're trying to get items created over 7 **minutes** ago?

Comment: Yes the SQL string works fine if I use the MSSQL driver, and if I run it in the DBVisualizer. The problem happen when I use JDTS driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in your statement, there are 3 possibilities.

```
store.id
service.id
serviceprovider.id
```

Debug this by removing portions of the statement, or executing it in the command line, until you figure out which reference to `.id` is causing you issue. I would highly suggest using naming such as

```
store.store_id
service.service_id
serviceprovider.serviceprovider_id
```

It makes debugging and readability a lot easier for you in the future.

Edit:

Try using the following statement. It does the same as yours (from what I can tell), but uses `JOINS` instead of `CROSSES`. It could make your debugging a bit easier.

```
SELECT tabledatastoreitem.name, tabledatastoreitem.path
FROM tabledatastoreitem
JOIN store ON store.id=tabledatastoreitem.store_id
JOIN service ON service.id = store.service_store_id
JOIN serviceprovider ON service.serviceprovider_id = serviceprovider.id
WHERE serviceprovider.name = 'SystemIService'
  AND store.createdttm < CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(MI, -7, GETDATE()));
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried to reduce the string and I got the same issue with the first store.id.

Comment: Could you update your question with the schemas? Generally, invalid column name is given when the column doesn't exist.

Comment: Mark when I run the same string with the microsoft's driver it works fine, also when I run it from dbVisualizer

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a statement using joins instead of crosses, could you try executing that and let me know what happens?

Comment: Thanks Mike but nothing, anyway your sql with join works well

Comment: Gotcha. Glad I could help then! If my answer solved your issue, feel free to upvote it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: No Mike. I still have a problem, your SQL works if I use sqljdbc4.jar or rather mssql driver but not with jstd driver

Comment: Ahh I see. Have you tried changing the table names as suggested and running again, that way we could determine which id it was firing an error off on?

Comment: Can you try breaking up your statement and executing smaller parts one at a time? `SELECT * FROM tabledatastoreitem, store, WHERE tabledatastoreitem.store_id = store.id`, and then add in each cross one at a time.

Comment: I did, it seems that he don't like store.id I found a way at list to delivery this app using microsoft driver. But I still to find a solution and understand what is different between jdts and mssql driver. Thanks again Mike for your help

Comment: Anytime, I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this could happen, but you could try escaping all instances of 'id' in the code to see if that fixes it:

```
SELECT tabledatastoreitem.name, tabledatastoreitem.path
FROM tabledatastoreitem, store, service, serviceprovider
WHERE tabledatastoreitem.store_id = store.[id]
    AND store.service_store_id = service.[id]
    AND service.serviceprovider_id = serviceprovider.[id]
    AND serviceprovider.name = 'SystemIService'
    AND store.createdttm < CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(MI, -7, GETDATE()));
```

Comment: Thanks Alvin, but nothing... :(